# Error handling in MySql view

Tags: mysql, view, error-handling

I am getting syntax issues while adding 'TRY'-'Catch' statement in the MySql views.

Could anyone suggest how to write exception handling in MySql View.

An early response is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's your real problem? Creating a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html) is very similar to a SELECT statement. I just don't understand where "exceptions" come into view ...

Comment: I am doing the extract and transformation part of some ETL process in a single view. In this case lets say if the source has a length of 50 character but destination has only 40 characters, I want to raise an error and stop the extraction at the same time and add that error message into some error file.

Comment: Maybe you and I understand the term `VIEW` differently. CREATE VIEW doesn't have any TRY ... CATCH functionality. So you can't add such a thing. Please share some code you have tried and the syntax error you've got.

Comment: @VMai I also understand the same about the view. But I have different requirements that I have to meet in the transformation logic. Try to share some piece of code soon.